# If nothing selected macro uses whole worksheet instead of showing error message

Tags: excel, range, selection, worksheet, vba

The macro offers the options to format selected text, which it does perfectly if some some cells are selected first.

However, the error handling is not working and I don't know why: if nothing is selected when I execute the macro, it formats the whole worksheet instead of showing an error message that requests a selection to be made. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Code from my UserForm ("UserForm1"):

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRange = Selection.SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeConstants)

If OptionUpper Then
    For Each cell In WorkRange
        cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End If
' code for the other options...

Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Code for calling the macro("Module1"):

```
Sub ChangeCase()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        UserForm1.Show
    Else
        MsgBox "Select an area first.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm using MS Excel 2010. (Hope I didn't forget any relevant information.)

Comment: *Something* has to be selected. If it's only one cell, then `SpecialCells` will use the whole sheet so you need to check that. Do you not want to allow the code to run on only one cell?

Comment: Oh, ok, that explains it. Well, I would need it for single columns, but I would like to make sure that I don't accidentally format the whole sheet if I happen to forget to make the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter the userform code to something like:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Dim WorkRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
'    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 then (I corrected this to the line below, then it worked!
     If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 then
   If Msgbox("Only one cell selected - do you want to format the whole sheet?", vbyesno) = vbNo then Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRange = Selection.SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeConstants)

If OptionUpper Then
    For Each cell In WorkRange
        cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End If
' code for the other options...

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A Much Better Solution to If nothing is selected.

```
Public Sub IfNoSelection()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Activate your Sheet
    Sheets("Name Of Sheet Here").Select

    'Select your range without selecting the header (column D)
    Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4)).Select

    'This Line Checks if what is selected is selected.
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) = 0 Then

    Else

    'enter code here

    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```